# How to define constraint for encoded parameter segment properly in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Say we have a path for user in our site, which is defined like this in `routes.rb`

```
get '/users/:username' => 'users#show', as: 'u', constraints: {username: /[A-Za-z0-9\_]+/}
```

it works well, and invalid username will just pass, then one day, we decide to allow people to use Chinese characters as a part of their usernames, the format will be extended to `/[\u4e00-\u9fa5A-Za-z0-9_]/`. So comes to the problem, because Chinese characters will be encoded to `%FF` format string, we can't use that constraint, how to define the constraint properly to make the rule work just like before?

I have tried to step back, just to make the route work, use `/[%A-Za-z0-9\_]+/` format, the income request will at least work, but when I call `u_path`, this constraint will just fail.

The problem is when to match request, Rails will use the origin incoming format, and when construct path, it will use the decoded format.

How to handle this situation?

I am using Rails 3.2.12.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't take the constrain out here and to controller/model?

Comment: It's an open source project, and I want to keep the constraint here to avoid too many changes.